# While checkout out, It again asks me to login. But user is already logged in

Tags: magento2

While checkout out, It again asks me to login. But user is already logged in. Even after loggin again and again, still it askes me to login. Website Link Kiabzanew.site.

This problem suddenly strated, I didnt even take the backup. But I checked online everyone is saying its a common Magento 2 problem. Please if anyone know any solution let me know.

Comment: Which Magento version do you have @Patrik ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya Magento 2.3.3

Comment: @Patrik, Have you installed any extension? Like Login to see price or something?

Comment: @Sanjay Gohil None.

Comment: This issue is fixed in Magento 2.3.3.

Comment: @Dhaduk Mitesh Then why am I facing this issue suddenly..